# Javascript breaks after div refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax function, which submits the data and refreshes the div after the data has been updated. The problem is that the jQuery elements within the div breaks after the form has been submitted, and the div has been refreshed.

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
tournamentid = getURLParameter('id');
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "button#submit" ,function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php?page=tourneys&id=" + tournamentid + "&action=teams&submit=true", //process to mail
            data: $('#swapteams').serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
                createNoty('The teams has been updated!', 'success');
// Refresh the div after submission
                $("#refresh").load("test.php?page=tourneys&id=" + tournamentid + "&action=teams #refresh");
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
              var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
              alert(err.Message);
}
        });
        return false;
    });
});
// the plugins and jQuery variables within the refresh div
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[id^="teamname"]').editable({
    ajaxOptions : {
        type : 'post'
    }
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select[id="swap"]').change(function(){
      $( "#saveprogress" ).show("fade");
    });
});
```

Comment: what do you mean by breaks

Comment: The jQuery features in the "refresh" div doesn't work after a refresh.

Comment: You're creating duplicate IDs, because this will put a new `#refresh` DIV inside the old `#refresh` DIV.

Comment: can you give an example... does it include event handlers, if so need to use event delegation... if there are plugins like jQuery UI, then you need to reinitialize them after refresh

Comment: `.load()` doesn't replace the element, it loads the new content _inside_ it.

Comment: Ahh right, is there a workaround for that?

Comment: `$("#refresh").load("test.php?page=tourneys&id=" + tournamentid + "&action=teams #refresh > *");` - it won't work is there is a text node as the direct child of refresh

Comment: another solution could be is to have the parent of `#refresh` to load(the parent should have only the refresh node as its child) - `$("#refresh").parent().load("test.php?page=tourneys&id=" + tournamentid + "&action=teams #refresh");`

Comment: Tried those, still doesn't work. I will edit the first post with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use event delegation to support dynamically added elements also you need to initialize the plugin again once the div is refreshed

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null
}
tournamentid = getURLParameter('id');
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', "button#submit", function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "test.php?page=tourneys&id=" + tournamentid + "&action=teams&submit=true", //process to mail
            data: $('#swapteams').serialize(),
            success: function (msg) {
                createNoty('The teams has been updated!', 'success');
                // Refresh the div after submission and pass a callback which will initialize the plugins
                $("#refresh").load("test.php?page=tourneys&id=" + tournamentid + "&action=teams #refresh", createEditable);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                alert(err.Message);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
// the plugins and jQuery variables within the refresh div
$(document).ready(createEditable);

function createEditable() {
    $('a[id^="teamname"]').editable({
        ajaxOptions: {
            type: 'post'
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    //use event delegation
    $(document).on('change', 'select[id="swap"]', function () {
        $("#saveprogress").show("fade");
    });
});
```